# CakePHP 2.1 calling Session Component in Plugin Component

Tags: session, plugins, cakephp-2.1

I have created a plugin in that i included one component.. So in that plugin component i have to include session component to call their methods write and read.. How to call those methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plugins still use the underlying Cake core, so in your plugin's AppController() you should be able to load the `SessionComponent` in the `$components` varaible. Here is an example `$components` setup:

```
public $components = array(
        'DebugKit.Toolbar',
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'),
            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login')
            ),
        'RequestHandler'
    );
```

Have you tried this?

Comment: This way you can access Session in the plugin AppController, but how do you access the SessionComponent in the plugin Component?

Comment: In any Component you have an instance of Controller. Through that you can call the SessionComponent and get the session data.

Comment: I'm looking at the [Component class](http://api.cakephp.org/view_source/component), and it looks like it doesn't have an instance of Controller. If you want to have it, you can save it in a variable in startup or initialize methods. Am I wrong?